# Преобразуем список кортежей в число

Tags: python

Есть:

```
number = [(7,)]
```

что необходимо предпринять чтобы я получил

```
>>> 7
```

Comment: ```number[0][0]```, - это ведь по сути многомерный массив.

Answer (score 0):

```
number = [(7, 5), (8, 'g') ]
otvet = []
for i  in number:
  for j in i:
    if str(j).isdecimal():
      otvet.append(j)
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in otvet))
```

Answer (score 0):

Краткий ответ:

```
number[0][0]
```

т.к. `number[0]` первый элемент списка, т.е. `(7,)`, из которого нужно взять первый элемент (индекс `[0]`) кортежи.